# Unreal Engine 5.1.1 Not writing to IOS Apple Game Center Leaderboards anymore

Tags: ios, game-engine, leaderboard, unreal-engine5, game-center-leaderboard

Leaderboards in unreal engine 5.1.1+ seem to no longer work. Last known working in 4.27.2. Has any one experienced the same issue or have a workaround. I cannot seem to write to leaderboard anymore.

Unreal Engine 5.1.1 Not writing to IOS Apple Game Center Leaderboards anymore. It used to in our previous 4.27 version but not anymore.

1.create blank project
2.In project settings enable game center
3.setup leaderboards in apple’s Game Center and submit it to go live, once live go back to unreal engine 5.1.1. Im attaching screenshot to show my apple Game Center setup to confirm that both my leaderboards are live, however inline with this example im using the leaderboard with the ID of highcoins.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqDlk.png)

4. Setup blueprint to login user to apple Game Center, make sure you fire the login to apple Game Center before you try to write to leaderboards or read from leaderboards. l setup blueprint to write to leaderboard (see screenshot that is attached)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsD6x.png)
5. package game (with all the nessisary certificates and profiles from apple, the usual stuff) and upload to transporter.
6. download game via test flight, or make go live ( I tried both)
7. open game can run bp to write to leaderboard and then read from leaderboard afterwards.
8. leaderboard does not write to IOS Apple Game Center, values still show  It looks like something happens when I press the button to submit score to leaderboard as there is a second or half a second lag like its sending information, however when I read from leaderboard there are no values logged in the apple Game Center. I also checked in apple Game Center portal and it does not show that any player scores are recorded.
   we even made blueprint force a store value as in the screenshot below, still no luck.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvtkj.png)

Any questions or if anyone was able to get this setup successfully or if you have a workaround